# Laravel 8 factory not found despite dumping composer autoloader

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm creating factories in my Laravel 8 project, I've used them before so am quite familiar with their set up.

In my project, I'm having trouble getting Laravel to pick up my factories and cannot figure out why, the error I'm getting is that my factory class can't be found, I've tried `composer dump-autoload` and also have tried various cache clearing commands with no result.

What am I missing?

My **database/factories/BrandFactory** is:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class BrandFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Brand::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $todo = $this->faker->unique()->company();
        $slug = Str::slug($brand);

        return [
            'user_id' => User::all()->random()->id,
            'brand' => $brand,
            'slug' => $slug,
            'url' => $this->faker->domain(),
            'created_at' => Carbon::now()->subDays(rand(1, 14))
        ];
    }
}
```

I have `HasFactory` on my model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Brand extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
    * The table associated with the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'brands';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'brand',
        'url'
    ];

    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = [
        'form'
    ];

    /**
     * Get the form associated with the user.
     */
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Form::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the brand that owns the comment.
     */
    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Which is called from my seeder:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App\Models\Brand;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Brand::factory(3)->create();
    }
}
```

Also, since this is a Laravel 8 project, autoloader is configured correctly to:

```json
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
}
```

Comment: try  protected $model = App\Models\Brand::class; in your factory

Comment: Tried implementing that, same error, I've got another project that simply uses `Model::class` and that works, I have cross-referenced any changes and they're the same, can't find anything obvious, what's strange is that the default User factory works fine.

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

Your code look fine, anyway, you can tell your model to find it's own factory using [newFactory](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#factory-and-model-discovery-conventions) method:

In your model:

```
protected static function newFactory()
{
    return Database\Factories\BrandFactory::new();
}
```